# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I understand adding two dates doesn't makes sense and subtraction gives us quantity but here I'm converting Timestamps o datetime by

```
pd.to_datetime()
```

Still I'm getting error.

```
0     2021-02-26 05:05:00
1     2021-02-26 05:10:00
2     2021-02-26 05:12:00
```

Here's dummy data.
If I need to add 05:05:00 and 05:10:00, how I'm supposed to do ?

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: I'm doing something like this: comptrip = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', index_col=False,header=0,infer_datetime_format=True)
comptrip['Job_Start'] = pd.to_datetime(comptrip['Job_Start'])

Comment: And what code failed with error `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'` ?

Comment: When I try comptrip['Job_Start][0] + comptrip['Job_Start][1]; I need few operations like this in my script

Comment: So need `comptrip['new'] = comptrip['Job_Start] + comptrip['Job_Start].shift()` ?

Comment: My Job_Start column saves duration and is converted from start and end columns that are timestamps too.. That's why this duration also looks like a timestamp and when I'm trying to calculate total duration of a machine ; it's giving me this error

Comment: Unfortuantely not understand, what is expected output here?

Comment: A way to convert 2021-02-26 05:05:00 into 05:05:00

Comment: you need to convert to timedelta; basically like `pd.to_timedelta(str(pd.to_datetime("2021-02-26 05:05:00").time()))`